React vite ssr dont let me to work with routes (Problem with react-router-dom)
Im working with react vite ssr the structure is the same as the example proyect create vite-react-ssr to makes landind pages but when I wanted to implement routes like about us o notfound there a lot of problemes like at the moment that I use BrowserRouter shows me
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at getUrlBasedHistory 
    at Object.createBrowserHistory (C:...node_modules\@remix-run\router\dist\router.cjs.js:234:10)
    at Module.createBrowserRouter (C:..\node_modules\react-router-dom\dist\umd\react-router-dom.development.js:269:23)
    at Index (C:...\src\index.jsx:8:20)
    at renderWithHooks (C:..node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5662:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (C:..node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5736:15)
    at renderElement (C:..node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5961:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\..node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6119:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (C:\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6091:14)
    at renderContextProvider (C:\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5935:3)
    at renderElement (C:\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6032:11)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6119:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (C:\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6091:14)
    at renderContextProvider (C:\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5935:3)
    at renderElement (C:\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6032:11)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6119:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6091:14)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (C:\\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5790:7)
    at renderElement (C:\\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5961:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6119:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (C:\\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6091:14)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (C:\\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5790:7)
    at renderElement (C:\\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:5961:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6119:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (C:\U\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6091:14)
    at retryTask (C:\\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6543:5)
    at performWork (C:\\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6591:7)
    at C:\\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6915:12
    at scheduleWork (C:\\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:78:3)
    at startWork (C:\\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6914:3)
    at renderToStringImpl (C:\\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6988:3)
    at Object.renderToString (C:\\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:7080:10)
    at render (C:\\src\entry-server.jsx:10:31)
    at file:///C://server.js:58:28
favicon.ico

index,jsx (Whit the both way that looks apparece the same error)
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Home } from './pages/Home'
import { Other } from './pages/Other'
import { NotFound } from './pages/NotFound'
import App from './App'
export const Index = () => {
    const routes = createBrowserRouter([
        {
            path: '/',
            element: <App/>,
            errorElement: <NotFound/>,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '/',
                    element: <Home/>
                }
            ]
        }
    ])
    return (
        /*<Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route index element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/other" element={<Other />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>*/



        <RouterProvider router={routes}/>
    )
}


entry-server.jsx
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import App from './App';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom/server'
import { Index } from '.';
import { Home } from './pages/Home';

export function render(url) {

  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
      <StaticRouter location={url}>
        <Index />
      </StaticRouter>
  )
  return { html }
}


entry-client.jsx
import './index.css'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import {Index} from './index'
import { Home } from './pages/Home'

ReactDOM.hydrateRoot(
  document.getElementById('root'),
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Index />
  </React.StrictMode>
)

I alredy tried diferents way to implement BrowserRouter but the same error, and I traied without the BrowserRouter and load the page and gives me this error
chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:21578 Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools
chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:200 Uncaught Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
    at invariant (chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:200:11)
    at useRoutesImpl (chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:3495:34)
    at useRoutes (chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:3492:10)
    at Routes (chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:4152:10)
    at renderWithHooks (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:11566:26)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:14944:21)
    at beginWork (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:15932:22)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:3672:22)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:3697:24)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:3731:39)
invariant @ chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:200
useRoutesImpl @ chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:3495
useRoutes @ chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:3492
Routes @ chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:4152
renderWithHooks @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:11566
mountIndeterminateComponent @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:14944
beginWork @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:15932
callCallback2 @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:3672
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:3697
invokeGuardedCallback @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:3731
beginWork$1 @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19791
performUnitOfWork @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19224
workLoopSync @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19163
renderRootSync @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19142
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:18704
workLoop @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:195
flushWork @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:174
performWorkUntilDeadline @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:382
Show 18 more frames
Show lessUnderstand this error
chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:519 Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <div>.
printWarning @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:519
error @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:503
errorHydratingContainer @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:8767
recoverFromConcurrentError @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:18759
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:18710
workLoop @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:195
flushWork @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:174
performWorkUntilDeadline @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:382
Show 8 more frames
Show lessUnderstand this error
chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:200 Uncaught Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
    at invariant (chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:200:11)
    at useRoutesImpl (chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:3495:34)
    at useRoutes (chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:3492:10)
    at Routes (chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:4152:10)
    at renderWithHooks (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:11566:26)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:14944:21)
    at beginWork (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:15932:22)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:3672:22)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:3697:24)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:3731:39)
invariant @ chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:200
useRoutesImpl @ chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:3495
useRoutes @ chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:3492
Routes @ chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:4152
renderWithHooks @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:11566
mountIndeterminateComponent @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:14944
beginWork @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:15932
callCallback2 @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:3672
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:3697
invokeGuardedCallback @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:3731
beginWork$1 @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19791
performUnitOfWork @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19224
workLoopSync @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19163
renderRootSync @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19142
recoverFromConcurrentError @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:18762
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:18710
workLoop @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:195
flushWork @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:174
performWorkUntilDeadline @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:382
Show 19 more frames
Show lessUnderstand this error
chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:14050 The above error occurred in the <Routes> component:

    at Routes (http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:4149:5)
    at Index

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:14050
update.callback @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:14070
callCallback @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:11266
commitUpdateQueue @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:11283
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:17113
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:18006
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:17995
commitLayoutEffects @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:17946
commitRootImpl @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19379
commitRoot @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19303
finishConcurrentRender @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:18786
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:18744
workLoop @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:195
flushWork @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:174
performWorkUntilDeadline @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:382
Show 15 more frames
Show lessUnderstand this error
chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:14778 Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
    at updateHostRoot (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:14778:65)
    at beginWork (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:15951:22)
    at beginWork$1 (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19779:22)
    at performUnitOfWork (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19224:20)
    at workLoopSync (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19163:13)
    at renderRootSync (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19142:15)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:18762:28)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:18710:30)
    at workLoop (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:195:42)
    at flushWork (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:174:22)
updateHostRoot @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:14778
beginWork @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:15951
beginWork$1 @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19779
performUnitOfWork @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19224
workLoopSync @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19163
renderRootSync @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19142
recoverFromConcurrentError @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:18762
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:18710
workLoop @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:195
flushWork @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:174
performWorkUntilDeadline @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:382
Show 11 more frames
Show lessUnderstand this error
chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19439 Uncaught Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
    at invariant (chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:200:11)
    at useRoutesImpl (chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:3495:34)
    at useRoutes (chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:3492:10)
    at Routes (chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:4152:10)
    at renderWithHooks (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:11566:26)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:14944:21)
    at beginWork (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:15932:22)
    at beginWork$1 (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19779:22)
    at performUnitOfWork (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19224:20)
    at workLoopSync (chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19163:13)
invariant @ chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:200
useRoutesImpl @ chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:3495
useRoutes @ chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:3492
Routes @ chunk-2NKYRYXZ.js?v=2725bec9:4152
renderWithHooks @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:11566
mountIndeterminateComponent @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:14944
beginWork @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:15932
beginWork$1 @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19779
performUnitOfWork @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19224
workLoopSync @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19163
renderRootSync @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:19142
recoverFromConcurrentError @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:18762
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:18710
workLoop @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:195
flushWork @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:174
performWorkUntilDeadline @ chunk-IURPBYAF.js?v=2725bec9:382
Show 16 more frames
Show lessUnderstand this error


You can Check this for Solution : Vite SSR + React Router Dom with Static Router.
Also you can use Latest Version of React Router Dom. Note that SSR not allowed to use BrowserRouter you can Use insted of Static Router

The reason of the error was that entry-server needed Static Router https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/StaticRouter
And the entry-client needed the BrowserRouter but need to be called an used on the own component, can not use on index.jsx so will look something like that
index.jsx
import React from 'react'
import { Routes, Route, createBrowserRouter, useRoutes } from 'react-        router-dom'
import { NotFound } from './pages/NotFound/NotFound'
import { ContactUs } from './pages/ContactUs/ContactUs'
import { HomePage } from './pages/HomePage/HomePage'
import { AboutUs } from './pages/AboutUs/AboutUs'
import App from './App'

export const Index = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<App/>}/>
                <Route index element={<HomePage/>} />
                <Route path="/about-us" element={<AboutUs/>} />
                <Route path='/contact-us' element={<ContactUs/>}/>
                <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
            </Routes>
        </>
    )
}

entry-client.jsx
//import './index.css'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { Index } from './index'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.hydrateRoot(
  document.getElementById('root'),
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Index />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
)

entry-server.jsx
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import App from './App';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom/server'
import { Index } from '.';

export function render(url) {

  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <StaticRouter location={url}>
        <Index />
      </StaticRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
  )
  return { html }
}

